# How can I implement a function that takes a string slice and returns a new string with all of the vowels removed?

Tags: string, rust, slice

**Problem**:

I'm trying to write a function in Rust that takes a string slice as input and returns a new string with all of the vowels removed. I'm having trouble figuring out how to iterate through the characters in the string and check if they are vowels.

**Question:**

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient or idiomatic way to implement this function in Rust. Can anyone suggest a better way to write this function, or point out any issues with my current approach?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
fn remove_vowels(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = String::new();

    // Iterate through the characters in the string
    for c in s.chars() {
        // Check if the character is a lowercase ASCII character that is not a vowel
        if !c.is_ascii_lowercase() || c != 'a' && c != 'e' && c != 'i' && c != 'o' && c != 'u' {
            result.push(c);
        }
    }

    result
}

fn main() {
    let s = "hello world";
    let s_without_vowels = remove_vowels(s);
    println!("{}", s_without_vowels);  // Output: "hll wrld"
}
```

Comment: I suggest `my_string.retain(is_non_vowel);`, where `fn is_non_vowel(c: char) -> bool` indicates whether a character should be retained. ([Documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.retain))

Comment: This question probably is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. StackOverflow is for specific programming questions. If you are looking for any kind of comment on working code, Code Review is a better choice.

Comment: In the nightly compiler, you could also use `remove_matched()`: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7af9d33b2654852df64c76e9fa5ec17d

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly correct and idiomatic, though it can be made more concise using built-ins.

You probably want to abstract `is_vowel` as a function `fn is_vowel(ch: &char) -> bool`. With that and using the built-in [`String::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.retain) mentioned in the comments, your code becomes simply

```rust
fn is_vowel(c: char) -> bool {
    c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'
}
fn remove_vowels(s: &str) -> String {
    let mut result = s.to_string();
    result.retain(|c| !is_vowel(c));
    result
}
```

Personally, I might leave out the `c.is_ascii_lowercase()` check (a possible premature optimization), but regardless it's good to comment explicitly that it is an optimization and not necessary for the logic.

```rust
fn is_vowel(c: char) -> bool {
    if !c.is_ascii_lowercase() {
        // shortcircuit optimization
        return false;
    }
    c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'
}
```

It's a bit problematic that the function doesn't check for upper-case or non-ascii vowels, so should probably be named differently, like `is_ascii_lowercase_vowel()`.

Finally, it's also worth knowing how to do this using iterators. This is much more generalizable to other use cases than `String::retain`. I would also expect it to be slightly faster as it is single-pass instead of double-pass. For these reasons, I personally find this to be the nicest implementation.

```rust
fn remove_vowels(s: &str) -> String {
    s.chars().filter(|&c| !is_vowel(c)).collect()
}
```